# Link to an outside site using a URLField from a model in Django

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to link to an outside site using a URLField from a model in the template?  I have the href link set up as a template variable, but the link is throwing a 404 error.

Here is my model.py:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
  # other fields
  link = models.URLField(blank=True)
```

views.py:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['blogs'] = Blog.objects.all()[:3]
    return context
```

my template.html:

```
   <ul class="thumbnails">
      {% if blogs %}
        {% for blog in blogs %}
        <li class="span3"> <a class="prdocutname mb10" href="#">{{ blog.title }}</a>
          <div class="thumbnail"> <a href="#"><img alt="{{ blog.title }}" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{ blog.picture }}" height="222" width="300"></a>
            <div class="price">
                <ul><li>{{ blog.story_description }}</li></ul>
            </div>
            <a href="{( blog.link )}">Go to Story</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
  </ul>
```

Everytime though when I click the link, it sends me to this URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/%7B(%20blog.link%20)%7D
```

and I get a 404 Error.
It looks like it is adding it onto local host instead of generating the absolute URL that is saved in the model.  Is there a way to fix this?

I am on Django 1.5, Python 2.7

Kind regards,
Aaron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
<a href="{{ blog.link }}">Go to Story</a>
```

Use `{{` pair to render variables.

Comment: Thanks guys! Just a typo then. I hate when typo's are the reasons that things don't work like they should!

Answer (score 1):

It should be `"{{ blog.link }}"` not `"{( blog.link )}"`.